# Issue with .push()

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm trying to do something really simple, but I think I'm making a stupid mistake.

I have an array full of objects, and I have a new object I want to put into that array. My code looks like this:

```
 var data = [ { id: 'S1', url: '1.html' } ];

 var newData = { id: '3', url: '3.html' };

console.log(data.push(newData))
```

For some reason, this keeps printing "2".

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/KqZBU/) is a fiddle

Can anyone tell me what stupid mistake I'm making?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using `.push()` correctly. But, are apparently expecting [a different `return` value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push):

> #### Returns
>
> The new [`length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) property of the object upon which the method was called.

If you're trying to log the `Array` itself, you'll want to do that separately:

```
data.push(newData);
console.log(data);
```

---

As for the fiddle, you can use [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to serialize the Objects.

```
data.push(newData);
$('#here').text(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2))
```

```
[ { "id": "S1", "url": "1.html" }, { "id": "3", "url": "3.html" } ]
```

Simply using `.text(data)` will use each [`Object`'s `toString()`](http://es5.github.io/#x15.2.4.2), which will simply result in:

```
[object Object],[object Object]
```

Answer (score 1):

`Array.protoype.push` mutates the array it is called on and returns the new length of the array.

[Check out the docs here!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)